# Navbar not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the code below:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light flex-column flex-md-row bg-faded rounded">
      <a class="navbar-brand mr-0 mr-md-2" href="/"><i class="fa fa-btc fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

      <div class="navbar-nav-scroll">
        <ul class="navbar-nav bd-navbar-nav flex-row mt-1">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/profile">Profile</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/conditions">Conditions</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/feedback">Feedback</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <a class="btn btn-default mb-3 mb-md-0 ml-md-3" href="http://twitter.com/btclottery2018" aria-label="Twitter">
        <i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </a>
    </header>
  </div>
</body>
```

My links are stuck together, but they must be the distance and the Twitter icon should be in the right corner. What is my mistake? What did I do wrong?

Comment: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/

Answer (score 1):

As per your code, you have included the bootstrap css, but the design need some more css for width, positioning and spacing of the elements.

Try to do it this way. Add the extra CSS.

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light flex-column flex-md-row bg-faded rounded">
      <a class="navbar-brand mr-0 mr-md-2" href="/"><i class="fa fa-btc fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

      <div class="navbar-nav-scroll">
        <ul class="navbar-nav bd-navbar-nav flex-row mt-1">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/profile">Profile</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/conditions">Conditions</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/feedback">Feedback</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <a class="btn btn-default mb-3 mb-md-0 ml-md-3" href="http://twitter.com/btclottery2018" aria-label="Twitter">
        <i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </a>
    </header>
  </div>
</body>
```

Extra CSS Part :-

```
.navbar-brand {
  float:left;
  width:10%;
}

header .navbar-nav-scroll {
  float: left;
  width:80%;
}

header .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: 25px;   
}

.navbar-nav li {
  float:left;
  padding:0px 20px;
  list-style:none;
}

.navbar-nav>li a {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  color:#000000;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.twitter-icon {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 25px;
  width:10%;
}
```

Comment: Only a partial answer. He asked what he is doing wrong. You only gave him code with no explanation of anything. That's not how SO works.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I have edited the answer for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your custom css

```
.navbar-nav .nav-link{
padding-right:10px;
}
```

Comment: If so , the links are shifted correctly, but the icon of Twitter is still left.

Comment: I see that your .btn class has text-align:center; but you can try 

.btn{
text-align:right;
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to do three things here:

1. You need to move the brand logo and the twitter icon inside individual li in the ul of navbar, for all of them to come in the same line.
2. You need to give the li containing the twitter icon a class of "navbar-right" so that it moves to the right.
3. You need to give a padding to the class "nav-items", something like this:

   .nav-items{
   padding:10px
   }

I'm attaching a JSFiddle for your reference. I hope this solves your problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/dk4v76rw/

```
  <div class="navbar-nav-scroll">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav bd-navbar-nav flex-row mt-1">

     <!--Add the navbar-brand in the ul-->
      <li> 
        <a class="navbar-brand mr-0 mr-md-2" href="/"><i class="fa fa-btc fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/profile">Profile</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/conditions">Conditions</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/feedback">Feedback</a>
      </li>

      <!--Add the icon as an li in the ul of the navbar and give it a class navbar-right-->
      <li class="navbar-right">
        <a class="btn btn-default mb-3 mb-md-0 ml-md-3 right" href="http://twitter.com/btclottery2018" aria-label="Twitter">
         <i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         </a>
     </li>

    </ul>   
 </div>


</header>
```

Comment: The Twitter icon should be in the right corner, and you have it is immediately after the link.

Answer (score -1):

Add this style in your style sheet.

```
.nav-item{
    margin-right:7px;
}
```